# ink-file-picker bug on Android with upload

Tags: filepicker.io

I try to use inkfilepicker.com on my project.
I have follow this guide: https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/android/

My code is simple but i can't have a valid URL when i pick from gallery or camera.

```
    private void selectImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FilePicker.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, FilePickerAPI.REQUEST_CODE_GETFILE);
    }

 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == FilePickerAPI.REQUEST_CODE_GETFILE) {
            if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
                // Result was cancelled by the user or there was an error
                return;
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            System.out.println("File path is " + uri.toString());
            System.out.println("Ink file URL: " + data.getExtras().getString("fpurl"));

        }
    }
```

I have this error on logcat.

```
10-17 11:07:27.887: W/System.err(31135): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to .. timed out
10-17 11:07:27.902: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to .. timed out
10-17 11:07:27.902: W/System.err(31135): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to .. timed out
10-17 11:07:27.907: W/System.err(31135): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to .. timed out
10-17 11:07:27.907: W/System.err(31135): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to .. timed out
10-17 11:07:27.907: W/System.err(31135): org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
10-17 11:07:27.912: W/System.err(31135):    at  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
10-17 11:07:27.917: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
10-17 11:07:27.917: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-17 11:07:27.917: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-17 11:07:27.917: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-17 11:07:27.922: W/System.err(31135):    at  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
10-17 11:07:27.922: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
10-17 11:07:27.922: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-17 11:07:27.947: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
10-17 11:07:27.962: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
10-17 11:07:27.967: W/System.err(31135):    at  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
10-17 11:07:28.042: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
10-17 11:07:28.067: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-17 11:07:28.067: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-17 11:07:28.077: W/System.err(31135): org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
10-17 11:07:28.077: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-17 11:07:28.077: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-17 11:07:28.077: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-17 11:07:28.077: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
10-17 11:07:28.077: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
10-17 11:07:28.082: W/System.err(31135):    at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:257)
10-17 11:07:28.082: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getStringFromNetworkRequest(FilePickerAPI.java:572)
10-17 11:07:28.082: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getPath(FilePickerAPI.java:344)
10-17 11:07:28.082: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-17 11:07:28.082: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
10-17 11:07:28.082: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
10-17 11:07:28.082: W/System.err(31135):    at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:257)
10-17 11:07:28.082: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getStringFromNetworkRequest(FilePickerAPI.java:572)
10-17 11:07:28.082: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getPath(FilePickerAPI.java:344)
10-17 11:07:28.082: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-17 11:07:28.082: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-17 11:07:28.082: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
10-17 11:07:28.082: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
10-17 11:07:28.082: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-17 11:07:28.087: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
10-17 11:07:28.087: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
10-17 11:07:28.087: W/System.err(31135):    at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:257)
10-17 11:07:28.087: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getStringFromNetworkRequest(FilePickerAPI.java:572)
10-17 11:07:28.092: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getPath(FilePickerAPI.java:344)
10-17 11:07:28.092: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:299)
10-17 11:07:28.092: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:1)
10-17 11:07:28.092: W/System.err(31135):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-17 11:07:28.092: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:299)
10-17 11:07:28.092: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:1)
10-17 11:07:28.097: W/System.err(31135):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-17 11:07:28.097: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-17 11:07:28.097: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-17 11:07:28.097: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-17 11:07:28.097: W/System.err(31135):    at  at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:299)
10-17 11:07:28.097: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:1)
10-17 11:07:28.097: W/System.err(31135):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-17 11:07:28.097: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-17 11:07:28.097: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-17 11:07:28.097: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-17 11:07:28.097: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-17 11:07:28.097: W/System.err(31135):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-17 11:07:28.097: W/System.err(31135): org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-17 11:07:28.097: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-17 11:07:28.097: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
10-17 11:07:28.102: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
10-17 11:07:28.102: W/System.err(31135):    at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:257)
10-17 11:07:28.102: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getStringFromNetworkRequest(FilePickerAPI.java:572)
10-17 11:07:28.102: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getPath(FilePickerAPI.java:344)
10-17 11:07:28.102: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:299)
10-17 11:07:28.102: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-17 11:07:28.102: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-17 11:07:28.102: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-17 11:07:28.112: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-17 11:07:28.112: W/System.err(31135):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-17 11:07:28.112: W/System.err(31135):    at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:257)
10-17 11:07:28.112: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getStringFromNetworkRequest(FilePickerAPI.java:572)
10-17 11:07:28.112: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getPath(FilePickerAPI.java:344)
10-17 11:07:28.112: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:1)
10-17 11:07:28.112: W/System.err(31135):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-17 11:07:28.112: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-17 11:07:28.112: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-17 11:07:28.117: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-17 11:07:28.117: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-17 11:07:28.117: W/System.err(31135):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-17 11:07:28.117: W/System.err(31135): java.io.IOException
10-17 11:07:28.117: W/System.err(31135): io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:299)
10-17 11:07:28.117: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:1)
10-17 11:07:28.117: W/System.err(31135):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-17 11:07:28.117: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-17 11:07:28.117: W/System.err(31135):    at java.io.IOException
10-17 11:07:28.117: W/System.err(31135): java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-17 11:07:28.117: W/System.err(31135):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-17 11:07:28.127: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-17 11:07:28.127: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-17 11:07:28.132: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-17 11:07:28.132: W/System.err(31135):    at java.io.IOException
10-17 11:07:28.132: W/System.err(31135): io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getStringFromNetworkRequest(FilePickerAPI.java:597)
10-17 11:07:28.132: W/System.err(31135):    at java.io.IOException
10-17 11:07:28.132: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getStringFromNetworkRequest(FilePickerAPI.java:597)
10-17 11:07:28.132: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getPath(FilePickerAPI.java:344)
10-17 11:07:28.132: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:299)
10-17 11:07:28.132: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:1)
10-17 11:07:28.132: W/System.err(31135):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-17 11:07:28.132: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-17 11:07:28.137: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-17 11:07:28.137: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-17 11:07:28.137: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-17 11:07:28.137: W/System.err(31135):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-17 11:07:28.142: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getStringFromNetworkRequest(FilePickerAPI.java:597)
10-17 11:07:28.142: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getPath(FilePickerAPI.java:344)
10-17 11:07:28.142: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:299)
10-17 11:07:28.142: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:1)
10-17 11:07:28.147: D/FilePickerAPI(31135): getPath path: /Flickr/
10-17 11:07:28.147: W/System.err(31135):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-17 11:07:28.147: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-17 11:07:28.147: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-17 11:07:28.147: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getPath(FilePickerAPI.java:344)
10-17 11:07:28.147: W/System.err(31135):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-17 11:07:28.147: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getStringFromNetworkRequest(FilePickerAPI.java:597)
10-17 11:07:28.147: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getPath(FilePickerAPI.java:344)
10-17 11:07:28.147: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:299)
10-17 11:07:28.147: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:1)
10-17 11:07:28.152: W/System.err(31135):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-17 11:07:28.152: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-17 11:07:28.152: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-17 11:07:28.152: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-17 11:07:28.152: W/System.err(31135):    at java.io.IOException
10-17 11:07:28.152: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getStringFromNetworkRequest(FilePickerAPI.java:597)
10-17 11:07:28.152: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getPath(FilePickerAPI.java:344)
10-17 11:07:28.152: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:299)
10-17 11:07:28.162: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:299)
10-17 11:07:28.162: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:1)
10-17 11:07:28.162: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-17 11:07:28.162: W/System.err(31135):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-17 11:07:28.162: W/System.err(31135): java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-17 11:07:28.162: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-17 11:07:28.162: W/System.err(31135):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-17 11:07:28.162: D/FilePickerAPI(31135): getPath path: /Picasa/
10-17 11:07:28.167: W/System.err(31135): io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:1)
10-17 11:07:28.167: W/System.err(31135):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-17 11:07:28.167: D/FilePickerAPI(31135): getPath path: /Box/
10-17 11:07:28.167: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-17 11:07:28.167: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-17 11:07:28.167: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-17 11:07:28.167: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-17 11:07:28.167: W/System.err(31135):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-17 11:07:28.167: W/System.err(31135): android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-17 11:07:28.167: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-17 11:07:28.167: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-17 11:07:28.167: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-17 11:07:28.167: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-17 11:07:28.167: W/System.err(31135):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-17 11:07:28.167: D/FilePickerAPI(31135): uploadFileToTemp
10-17 11:07:49.837: W/System.err(31135): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x4dd41b80: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
10-17 11:07:49.837: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
10-17 11:07:49.837: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:371)
10-17 11:07:49.842: W/System.err(31135):    at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:209)
10-17 11:07:49.842: W/System.err(31135):    at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:355)
10-17 11:07:49.842: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:375)
10-17 11:07:49.842: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
10-17 11:07:49.842: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-17 11:07:49.842: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-17 11:07:49.842: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-17 11:07:49.842: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
10-17 11:07:49.842: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
10-17 11:07:49.842: W/System.err(31135):    at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:257)
10-17 11:07:49.842: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getStringFromNetworkRequest(FilePickerAPI.java:572)
10-17 11:07:49.842: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getPath(FilePickerAPI.java:344)
10-17 11:07:49.852: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:299)
10-17 11:07:49.852: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:1)
10-17 11:07:49.852: W/System.err(31135):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-17 11:07:49.852: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-17 11:07:49.852: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-17 11:07:49.852: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-17 11:07:49.852: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-17 11:07:49.852: W/System.err(31135):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-17 11:07:49.857: W/System.err(31135): java.io.IOException
10-17 11:07:49.857: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getStringFromNetworkRequest(FilePickerAPI.java:597)
10-17 11:07:49.857: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getPath(FilePickerAPI.java:344)
10-17 11:07:49.857: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:299)
10-17 11:07:49.857: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI$PrecacheTask.doInBackground(FilePickerAPI.java:1)
10-17 11:07:49.857: W/System.err(31135):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-17 11:07:49.857: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-17 11:07:49.857: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-17 11:07:49.857: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-17 11:07:49.857: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-17 11:07:49.857: W/System.err(31135):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-17 11:07:50.157: W/System.err(31135): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x4d500580: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
10-17 11:07:50.157: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
10-17 11:07:50.157: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:371)
10-17 11:07:50.157: W/System.err(31135):    at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:209)
10-17 11:07:50.157: W/System.err(31135):    at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:355)
10-17 11:07:50.157: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:375)
10-17 11:07:50.162: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
10-17 11:07:50.162: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-17 11:07:50.162: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-17 11:07:50.162: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-17 11:07:50.162: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
10-17 11:07:50.162: W/System.err(31135):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
10-17 11:07:50.162: W/System.err(31135):    at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:257)
10-17 11:07:50.162: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getStringFromNetworkRequest(FilePickerAPI.java:572)
10-17 11:07:50.162: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.uploadFileToTemp(FilePickerAPI.java:463)
10-17 11:07:50.162: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePicker$UploadLocalFileTask.doInBackground(FilePicker.java:313)
10-17 11:07:50.167: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePicker$UploadLocalFileTask.doInBackground(FilePicker.java:1)
10-17 11:07:50.167: W/System.err(31135):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-17 11:07:50.167: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-17 11:07:50.167: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-17 11:07:50.167: W/System.err(31135):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-17 11:07:50.167: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-17 11:07:50.167: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-17 11:07:50.172: W/System.err(31135):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-17 11:07:50.172: W/System.err(31135): java.io.IOException
10-17 11:07:50.172: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getStringFromNetworkRequest(FilePickerAPI.java:597)
10-17 11:07:50.172: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.uploadFileToTemp(FilePickerAPI.java:463)
10-17 11:07:50.172: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePicker$UploadLocalFileTask.doInBackground(FilePicker.java:313)
10-17 11:07:50.172: W/System.err(31135):    at io.filepicker.FilePicker$UploadLocalFileTask.doInBackground(FilePicker.java:1)
10-17 11:07:50.177: W/System.err(31135):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-17 11:07:50.177: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-17 11:07:50.177: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-17 11:07:50.177: W/System.err(31135):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-17 11:07:50.177: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-17 11:07:50.177: W/System.err(31135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-17 11:07:50.177: W/System.err(31135):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-17 11:07:50.232: I/System.out(31135): File path is file:///data/data/com.myapp/cache/fpf1171445028.jpg
10-17 11:07:50.232: I/System.out(31135): Ink file URL:
```

What's the problem ?